# creating a dict iterating through two nested loops and a JSON output

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary out of two lists - envs and coms - and a JSON output (each for every *env-com* combination) like the script below. The resultant dictionary that I like to have should be something similar to this:

```
{
    "live-business-data-infrastructure": {
        "component": "traveldb", 
        "environment": "test"
    }, 
    { .... }
}
```

This just a sample I made out of the original script to demonstrate what I'm after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json 
envs = [ 'test','live', ]  ## originallt: [ 'test','live',... ]
coms = [ 'traveldb' ]      ## originally: [ 'traveldb','weatherbot',... ]
test_traveldb_stks = [ {
                          "main_stack": 'false',
                          "name": "test-business-data-resources"
                        },
                        {
                          "main_stack": 'true',
                          "name": "test-business-data-infrastructure"
                        }
                      ]
live_traveldb_stks = [ {
                          "main_stack": 'false',
                          "name": "live-business-data-resources"
                        },
                        {
                          "main_stack": 'true',
                          "name": "live-business-data-infrastructure"
                        }
                      ]

aList = []; sDict = {}

for env in envs:
    for com in coms:
        aList.extend([ zz['name'] for zz in eval(env+'_'+com+'_stks') ])
        sDict[aList[-1]] = { 'component':com, 'environment':env }

#print(aList)
print(json.dumps(sDict, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Which is pretty much working but missing out some data because of `sDict[aList[-1]]` bit in the script but couldn't quite figure out how can I iterate through two nested loops and map that with the JSON to get the desired dict. Any suggestion(s)? Let me know if I didn't make it very clear. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are quite close, but why are you only taking the last item in `aList`? By using `extend` instead of `append` you get

```
aList = [olditem, olditem, newitem, newitem]
                                  # ^ aList[0]
```

not

```
aList = [[olditem, olditem], [newitem, newitem]]
                           # ^ aList[0]
```

Also, you need to loop through the items. Try:

```
aList = []
sDict = {}
for com in coms:
    for env in envs:
        for d in eval("{0}_{1}_stks".format(env, com)):
            aList.append(d["name"]) # add name from d to end of aList
            sDict[d["name"]] = {'component': com, 'environment': env}
```

Note that you can leave out `aList = []` and `aList.append(...)` if you were only using that to fill `sDict` and don't have further use for it.

Comment: I like that. Two questions though: what's the use of `aList.append(d["name"])` here? and I `"{}_{}_stks"` doesn't work for me, I had to go with `"{0}_{1}_stks"` instead. Testing it out in my original script at the moment. Cheers!!

Comment: The `{}`/`{0}` issue is a Python 2.x vs. 3.x thing. I've updated my answer with that and comments.